# Paypal Transaction (Push notification on iOS device)

Tags: ios, paypal, push-notification

I want to send push notification on the iOS device(logged in state) whenever any transaction occurs related to that PayPal account.

Transaction occurring related to that account anywhere (whether on PayPal website or on mobile device)
Push notification in both case.

How can this functionality be achieved using  PayPal iOS sdk?
or any other way....

Answer (score 2):

When there is transaction with `PayPal` then after successful transaction, it will return with a reference id you can check it on device. You get it OR not if yes then you can invoke the `push Notification` service.

But you can't do it just after money transaction because control will be on `PayPal` page so you can't detect any event occurring on that page

Comment: Thanx for your reply
But I am asking about any transaction occurring related to that account on both mobile and on website or anywhere
(transaction occurring on that account even from website)

Comment: NO, You can't. Because you have not authorize to detect that occurrence of events.

Comment: Can this functionality be acheived using  IPN (Instant payment Notification) or any other PayPal sdk APi

Answer (score 1):

There are few PayPal delegates which are called on behalf of Transaction state as

```
#pragma mark - PayPalPaymentDelegate methods

- (void)payPalPaymentDidComplete:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
    // Payment was processed successfully; send to server for verification and fulfillment.
    [self verifyCompletedPayment:completedPayment];

    // Dismiss the PayPalPaymentViewController.

}

- (void)payPalPaymentDidCancel {
    // The payment was canceled; dismiss the PayPalPaymentViewController.
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)verifyCompletedPayment:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
    // Send the entire confirmation dictionary
    NSData *confirmation = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:completedPayment.confirmation
                                                           options:0
                                                             error:nil];


}
```

So in delegate **payPalPaymentDidComplete** you can **send confirmation to your server; your server should verify the proof of payment and give the user their goods or services and notify user with PUSH Notification** . If the server is not reachable, save the confirmation and try again later.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply
I am totally aware about these delegate methods
But I am concerned about the transaction occuring related to that account on PayPal website
Push notification on device even in that case

Comment: You can hit an api to notify server for PUSH notification after successful transaction as per your requirement as stated in my updated answer.

Comment: @Nishant his requirment is some what different he just want to notify when ever money deducts from account, its not controllable from programming. are you agree ?

Comment: But in case of transaction occurring on PayPal website
there is no  involvement of iOS device. so no delegate is fired in that case
Can this functionality be acheived using PayPal IPN (Instant payment Notification) or any other PayPal sdk API